Implementing oauth + jwt (+ bearer token) with Ktor server plugins
I am implementing authentication in my Ktor app, using an Oauth provider who issues JWT tokens as response. I get the callback, and receive the access token, then manually go and fetch the refresh & id token from the provider.
This all works well and I can validate the JWT against the provider's public key manually.
I'd now like to attach JWT authentication onto my app as the user will have their session. However I'm not sure if this is the correct solution.
My ouath callback redirects the client into a jwt protected endpoint, as I'd expect their authenticated cookie to be set in their header.
But when debugging the onAuthenticate method within ktor-server-auth JWTAuthenticationProvider, the authHeader is always null. I believe I have missed some configuration or manual step to set the returned JWT in the Authorization header of the client's callback, or on the session itself. This seems to be handled by the Bearer token authentication plugin, I wanted to confirm this is a good plan before I head down that path.
Is it best practice to set login + callback as oauth, and the rest of the app's protected resources as JWT authenticated, or is this all combined in the Oauth already?
Note, the returned JWT has multiple claims. One potential miss is having to use local storage for the tokens and just giving the client a session header to use as an identifier.
install (Authentication) {
  jwt("jwt-cookie") {
    verifier(
      issuer = "my-issuer-url",
      audience = "my-audience",
      algorithm = RSA256(myKeyProvider)
    )
    validate { credential ->
      if (credential.payload.getClaim("sub").asString() != "")
        JWTPrincipal(credential.payload)
      else
        null
    }
    challenge {
      call.respond(Unauthorized)
    }
  }
  
  oauth("cookie-provider") {
    urlProvider = { "https://myUrlProvider:port/callback" }
    providerLookup = {
      OauthServerSettings.Oauth2ServerSettings(
        name = "cookie-provider",
        authorizeUrl = "my-authorize-url",
        accessTokenUrl = "my-access-token-url",
        requestMethod = Post,
        clientId = "myClientId",
        passParamsInURL = true
      )
    }
  }

routing {
  authenticate("cookie-provider") {
    get("/login") { }
    
    get("/callback") {
        val accessCode = call.request.queryParameters["code"]
        val state = call.request.queryParameters["state"]
        if (accessCode != null && state != null) {
          val token = myProviderCient.fetchToken(accessCode)
          call.sessions.set(UserSession(state, token.refresh))
          call.respondRedirect("/welcome")
        }
    }
  }
  
  authenticate("jwt-cookie") {
    get("/welcome") {
      val principal = call.principal<JWTPrincipal>()
      val userID = principal?.payload?.getClaim("UserId")
      call.responseText("Hello, $userID!")
    }
  }
}


A client cannot be redirected with the Authorization header set. You can use the session authentication (https://ktor.io/docs/server-session-auth.html) to protect the /welcome route since the session is set in the /callback route. However, the JWT authentication won't be needed then.

Alright, I will manually validate the JWT response from my provider and then assign a session to the user. The ktor JWT authentication plugin may have been nice to avoid the manual but I understand it is not part of the usual oauth flow.
